# Elasticsearch: mapper_parsing_exception: Get detailed error message

Tags: python, pandas, elasticsearch

I am inserting a Pandas dataframe into Elasticsearch, using the `elasticsearch` Python package.

I have created an index specifying an explicit mapping:

```
mappings = {
    'properties': {
        'PLZ': {'type': 'integer'},
        'ORT': {'type': 'text'},
        'STRASSE': {'type': 'text'},
        ...
}

es.indices.create(index="test", mappings = mappings)
```

When I try to insert a specific document into this index, I receive a *mapper_parsing_exception*:

```
res = es.index(index="test", id=1, document=df.iloc[0], error_trace = True)
```

*BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'failed to parse')*

Is there any way to receive a more detailed error message describing which field exactly could not be parsed?

Comment: You can find a detailed error message in your ES server logs, feel free to share it here

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast responses :)
In which log file do I have to look?
In *<elastic directory>/logs* there are various log files: *elasticsearch.log, elasticsearch_server.json, gc.log, ...*  
But they contain only log messages on INFO level. The last message was for creating the index: `[2022-12-13T17:26:38,619][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetadataCreateIndexService] [...] [test] creating index, cause [auto(bulk api)], templates [], shards [1]/[1]`

Comment: Try to use Kibana Dev Tools to index the document manually and you'll see the error in the result window

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sending a single document to Elastic (using the Kibana Dev Tools or a curl PUT request) gave me a detailled error message. The reason were NaN values within the JSON object. NaN values should actually be converted to `null` in JSON.
Still a bit disappointed that the `es.index()` function itself does not provide a detailled error message.